# I want to use my alert box for multiple times to enter the data in android?

Tags: android

```
  adMedcenter.setPositiveButton(R.string.Ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            edtMedname=(EditText)adAlert.findViewById(R.id.tvMed);
            edtMedid=(EditText)adAlert.findViewById(R.id.tvId);
            edtMedad=(EditText)adAlert.findViewById(R.id.tvaddrs);
            details=new Detail(edtMedname.getText().toString(),edtMedid.getText().toString(),edtMedad.getText().toString());
            detailsInflater=getLayoutInflater();
            inflaterView=detailsInflater.inflate(R.layout.inflate_add,null);
            ivIcon=(ImageView)inflaterView.findViewById(R.id.ivMedicon);
            txtMedName=(TextView)inflaterView.findViewById(R.id.tvMedname);
            txtMedId=(TextView)inflaterView.findViewById(R.id.tvMedid);
            txtMedAd=(TextView)inflaterView.findViewById(R.id.tvMedAddress);
            ivIcon.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.ivicon,null));
            txtMedName.setText(details.getStrMedname());
            txtMedId.setText(insert+details.getStrId());
            txtMedAd.setText(details.getStrAddress());
            rlContain.addView(inflaterView);
        }
    });
```

This is the code ,i have created for Alert box ok button ,but i want to get it multiple times .

Comment: call the alert dialog in  loop ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you tap on OK button on popup then call (show) AlertDialog again.